# How to start empathy and steam on different workspace / viewport

Tags: unity, compiz, empathy, workspaces, steam

The applications empathy and steam should start on different workspaces / viewports.

In the tool `ccsm` there is the configuration option

**Window Management > Place Windows > Fixed Window Placement > Windows with fixed viewport**

Here I added configuration settings for pidgin, skype, empathy and steam.
However the settings for steam and empathy do not work. They always open on the current workspace / viewport.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's possible that they have a different title, run `xwininfo` in terminal, click on the Steam window and check the output

Comment: @minerz029 Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: What was printed in the terminal when you did that?

Comment: [xwininfo](http://0bin.net/paste/znGD8bV0p7HEJw5R#ZE0aLOWMmbGnTI+AFZUHaakP6PcWGAYAo9aAqSRhmy4=) For Steam it might be the problem that first the login window opens and after it closes the real steam window is opened. I clicked on the real steam window here.

Comment: So what'd it say? Try specifying the exe path ( if possible) in ccsm instead. I'll try later with my steam

Comment: xwininfo in my comment is a link to the pastebin. There is no option to use the exe path.